# Enabling Communication between different webroles on Azure Cloud

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network

We are trying to build a cloud service on Azure. We have 3 webrole instances running. What are the possible ways to proxy the requests that we get on a webrole to some other webrole.

For Example,
I have the following 2 web roles running: webrole0, webrole1.

I get a request on webrole0. Based on some parameters either webrole0 can serve the request or the request needs to be proxied to webrole1. How do I make this proxying of the request possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the path based routing you can go with Azure Application Gateway. If you want to route traffic to web roles based on the request parameters, you need to go with third party NVAs like F5 to check if that satisfies your routing needs.